# How to pass jenkins build environment into pod using kubernetes plugin?

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Env: Jenkins 2.73.1 & Kubernetes plugin  1.0

Inside the container, I like to get the normal jenkins build environment variable like `BUILD_NUMBER`

```
podTemplate(label: 'mypod', containers: [
    containerTemplate(name: 'python', image: 'python:2.7.8', ttyEnabled: true)
]) {

    node("mypod") {
        echo sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'env')

        container('python') {
            stage('Checkout') {
                sh "env"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So far in the code above, inside `python`, it doesn't have the traditional build variable.

Any solution to get those variables inside container?

Comment: I am getting error : Jenkins doesn’t have label mypod in jenkins and not able to start POD. Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use env.BUILD_NUMBER
i.e.

```
node{
    echo env.BUILD_NUMBER
}
```

Also if you want a list of all the env vars that are available you can run

```
node{
    echo "${env.getEnvironment()}"
}
```

These are the default jenkins plugins env vars but you can also set env vars for your kubernetes plugin build pods in the pod template, for example..

```
envVars: [
  envVar(key: 'GOPATH', value: '/home/jenkins/go')
]),
```

FWIW here's that code being used https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8-pipeline-library/blob/3834f0f/vars/goTemplate.groovy#L27

More details [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin#pod-and-container-template-configuration)

Comment: how to pass $BUILD_NUMBER into container? can u provide working code ?